# How to set a map with enum as key and an obj as value in Spring 2.5?

Tags: java, spring

```
public class Foo {
   public enum myEnum {ONE, TWO};
}

public class Var {

}

public class Dummy {
    Map<myEnum, Var> myMap = null
}
```

My xml file

```
<bean id="enumOne" class="com.myClass.Foo.myEnum" factory-method="valueOf">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>One</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I got an error message:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, com.myClass.Foo.myEnum

How do I set a map with enum keys using Spring framework 2.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've explained in another question of yours, the correct qualified class name for your nested `enum` is

```
Foo$myEnum
```

Obviously appended to whatever package it is in, possibly

```
com.myClass.Foo$myEnum
```

Note that java naming convention states that package names should be lowercase and that a type name (interface, class, or enum) should start with an uppercase character.

Also, your enum constant is named `ONE` so that's how you would refer to it with `valueOf`. For example

```
myEnum.valueOf("ONE");
```

Therefore, your `bean` declaration becomes

```
<bean id="enumOne" class="com.myClass.Foo$myEnum" factory-method="valueOf">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>ONE</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

As for the map, use `util:map` with the correct qualified class name (change your `String` to whatever type you want to use)

```
<util:map id="aMap" map-class="java.util.HashMap" key-type="com.myClass.Foo$myEnum" value-type="java.lang.String">
    <entry>
        <key>
            <ref bean="enumOne"/>
        </key>
        <value>
            Hello World
        </value>
    </entry>
</util:map>
```

Comment: @Vidya If I need to spoon feed everything, fine. The issue is the `ClassNotFoundException`. Fix that, and you reference the bean as a key just fine.

Comment: @Vidya How does my answer not explain what is wrong? It explains exactly that the qualified class name wasn't specified correctly. That's why OP was getting `ClassNotFoundException`. For the `Map`, sure, use `util:map`. I'm not saying you were wrong with that. But that, on it own, does not do anything for OP's situation.

Comment: Sotirios below: "Then perhaps that person correctly downvoted because your answer is wrong." Sotirios above: "I'm not saying you were wrong with that." Haha that's awesome. Anyway, here are two solid answers. I hope one of them helps the OP move forward.

Comment: @Vidya Your _answer_ is wrong because it won't fix OP's `ClassNotFoundException`. Your suggestion to use `util:map` is good. You can't just take OP's question `How do I set a map with enum keys using Spring framework 2.5?` You have to take it in context.

Comment: @Vidya I don't understand your reasoning. You propose to simply change the name of the enum from `myEnum` to `MyEnum`. And then you use `Foo.MyEnum` as the `key-type`. This is wrong. The enum is a nested member of the `Foo` class. As such, it has to be referenced as `...Foo$MyEnum` (depending on case). That's the thing that is wrong with your answer. Without it, OP would still get a `ClassNotFoundException` for Spring 2.5.

Comment: @Vidya Do you understand why your answer is incomplete? Maybe that is why someone donwvoted. Or maybe they didn't understand your answer fully. because you only give code but don't explain it.

Comment: @vidya It's definitely bad form not to comment after downvoting answers.