# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error using enum as a key in Map

Tags: java, spring, enums

```
<util:map id="myMap" key-type="com.myClass.Foo.myEnum" value-type="com.myClass.Foo">
    <entry>
        <key>
            <value type="com.myClass.Foo.myEnum">ONE</value>
        </key>
        <ref bean="myObj"/>
    </entry>
</util:map>
```

Java:

```
package com.myClass
public class Foo {
    public enum myEnum {ONE, TWO;}
}
```

I am trying to create a map from Spring 2.5.

```
Map<myEnum, Foo> myMap;
```

I am getting

```
nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.myClass.Foo.myEnum
```

I definitely have `com.myClass.Foo.myEnum`in `com.myClass.Foo` I don't know why I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: possible duplicate [spring2.5 how to set a map with enum as key and an obj as value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601077/spring2-5-how-to-set-a-map-with-enum-as-key-and-an-obj-as-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your enum class' fully qualified name is

```
com.myClass.Foo$myEnum
```

not

```
com.myClass.Foo.myEnum
```

Switch it and it will work. Spring uses reflection, with `Class.forName()` to get the `Class` object for your class and to instantiate an object. `forName()` expects a fully qualified name. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117753/what-means-java-filenames-with-a-dollar-sign-and-a-number-class-in-it-name1-c) to understand why your class name contains a `$`.

Note that in newer versions of Spring, there's a `catch` block that catches the `ClassNotFoundException` and tries `forName` again after replacing the last `.` with a `$`.